# $\cos \left(\frac{2\pi }{7}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\cos \left(\frac{4\pi }{7}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\cos \left(\frac{6\pi }{7}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} =?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been trying to solve the following question for a long time:

Find $a,b,c,d$ such that: ($a,b,c,d$ are primes)

> $\cos \left(\frac{2\pi }{7}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\cos \left(\frac{4\pi }{7}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\cos \left(\frac{6\pi }{7}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \left(\frac{a-b\sqrt[3]{c}}{d}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} $

What I have tried so far is that:

Let $x=\cos \left(\frac{2\pi }{7}\right), y=\cos \left(\frac{4\pi }{7}\right),z=\cos \left(\frac{6\pi }{7}\right)$, then

$x+y+z=-1/2$,

$xyz =1/8 $

$xy+yz+zx=-1/2$

So, $x,y,z$ are the roots of $8t^3+4t^2-4t-1=0$ and can be found by Cardan's method and hence $x^{1/3}+y^{1/3}+z^{1/3}$ can be found. However that method was way too long and it seems that the question may have a more elegant solution (given the form).

Also, I tried to cube both sides of the equation in the question and substitute using the above three relations, but that required the value of $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}+z^{2/3}$, which I coundn't find.

Would someone pls help me out (without using Cardan)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check Theorem 2 and Example 2 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.3420.pdf). That might be helpful.

Comment: Let $x^3=\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}$ and so on, then $x^3+y^3+z^3=-\frac{1}{2}$, $xyz=\frac{1}{2}$, $x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^3=-\frac{1}{2}$. Let $x+y+z=u$, $xy+xz+yz=v$. Then $u^3-3uv=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz$, $v^3-3uv(xyz)=x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^2-3x^2y^2z^2$.
Then $u^3-3uv=-2$, $4v^3-6uv=-5$. Then $4u^3v^3=(3uv-2)(6uv-5)$. Let $uv=w$, then $4w^3-(3w-2)(6w-5)=0$, $4w^3-18w^2+27w-10=0$. $w=\frac{3-\sqrt[3]{7}}{2}$. $u^3=3w-2=\frac{5-3\sqrt[3]{7}}{2}$, $u=\sqrt[3]{\frac{5-3\sqrt[3]{7}}{2}}$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Wow, this was nice, thanks!

Comment: @Feng Thanks for the paper... Was helpful :)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3326583/686284

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Ramanujan's cubic polynomial, this polynomial don't need to find 3 roots. If coefficients are satisfied the condition, then sum of cuberoots of zeroes can be evaluated directly from its coefficients.

EDIT: With your results, you established the equation: $8t^3+4t^2-4t-1=0$ which is equivalent $t^3+\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{1}{8}=0$

The Ramanujan's cubic polynomial said that: If the polynomial $x^3+px^2+qx+r$ has 3 real roots $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and the relation $pr^{\frac{1}{3}}+3r^{\frac{2}{3}}+q=0$ then $x_1^{\frac{1}{3}}+ x_2^{\frac{1}{3}}+ x_3^{\frac{1}{3}}=\left(-p-6r^{\frac{1}{3}}+3(9r-pq)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Back to our case: $p=\frac{1}{2}, q=-\frac{1}{2}, r=-\frac{1}{8}$ and $pr^{\frac{1}{3}}+3r^{\frac{2}{3}}+q=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+3\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2}=0$ then you can calculate the sum of cuberoot of zeroes follow the relation with $x_1, x_2, x_3$. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I am very sorry, just want to help, but i need 50 reputation to add comment. If i violate the rule, you can delete my answer, i will obey the rule. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PelikanSH037 Thank you very much!

Comment: @Shashwat1337 You are very welcome, thank you.