# Find the value of: $\sqrt[3]{a+b}+\sqrt[3]{b+c}+\sqrt[3]{a+c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, roots, radicals, cubics

> Let $a,b,c$ be roots of the cubic
> $$x^3-x^2-2x+1=0$$
> Then, find the value of:
> $$\sqrt[3]{a+b}+\sqrt[3]{b+c}+\sqrt[3]{a+c}$$

My attempt.

I used the substitutions $$a+b=x^3, b+c=y^3, a+c=z^3$$

$$x^3+y^3+z^3=2(a+b+c)=2$$

Then I used the identity $$x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y+z)^3-3(x+y+z)(xy+yz+xz)+3xyz$$

But I stuck here. I can not simplify $$xy+yz+xz$$

Comment: I may be mixing up the coefficients, but don't you have $a+b+c=-1,ab+bc+ac=2$?

Comment: @abiessu Yes. Right

Comment: @abiessu WoW. Still there is no comment/answer

Comment: In case of interest, this is the minimal polynomial of $-2\cos \frac{2\pi}7$, and belongs to a family of polynomials described here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1067992/4781

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the given cubic, we know that $a+b+c=1$, therefore
$$\sqrt[3]{a+b}+\sqrt[3]{b+c}+\sqrt[3]{a+c}=\sqrt[3]{1-c}+\sqrt[3]{1-a}+\sqrt[3]{1-b}=\sqrt[3]{A}+\sqrt[3]{B}+\sqrt[3]{C}$$
where $A,B,C$ are the roots of
$(1-x)^3-(1-x)^2-2(1-x)+1=0$, that is $x^3-2 x^2-x+1=0$.
It can be shown (see for example this [link](https://socratic.org/questions/find-the-cubic-equation-whose-roots-are-the-cubes-of-the-roots-of-x-3-ax-2-bx-c-)) that
$$x^3+(\alpha^3−3\alpha\beta +3\gamma)x^2+
(\beta^3−3\alpha\beta \gamma+3\gamma^2)x+\gamma^3=0$$
is the cubic equation whose roots are the cubes of the roots of $x^3+\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma=0$. So it remains to find $-\alpha$ in the system
$$\begin{cases}
\alpha^3−3\alpha\beta +3\gamma=-2\\
\beta^3−3\alpha\beta \gamma+3\gamma^2=-1\\
\gamma^3=1
\end{cases}$$
which boils down to $\gamma=1$, $\beta=\frac{\alpha^3+5}{3\alpha}$ and
$$(\alpha^3+5)^3-27\alpha^3(\alpha^3+5)+4\cdot 27\alpha^3=0$$
or
$$\alpha^9-12\alpha^6+48\alpha^3+125=(\alpha^3-4)^3+189=0$$
which has just one real root at $\alpha=-\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{7}-4}$.
Hence
$$\sqrt[3]{a+b}+\sqrt[3]{b+c}+\sqrt[3]{a+c}=-\alpha=\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{7}-4}\approx 1.20249.$$

P.S. Notice that the roots $a,b,c$ of the cubic polynomial $f(x)=x^3-x^2-2x+1$ are three distinct real numbers (one is negative and two are positive) because $f(−2)<0$, $f(0)>0$, $f(1)<0$, $f(2)>0$.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to expand your answer?

Comment: But how do you know that, the answer is real ?

Comment: "But how do you know that, the answer is real?" Because the given cubic $x^3-x^2-2x+1=0$ has three real roots.

Comment: Then how do you know that, all roots are real?

Comment: If $f(x)=x^3-x^2-2x+1$ then $f(-2)<0$, $f(0)>0$, $f(1)<0$, $f(2)>0$ then apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Can you provide an elementary way?

Comment: Only for high school level. There is no such a theorem in highschool program

Comment: Are you asking an elementary way for showing that $f(x)=x^3-x^2-2x+1$ has three distinct real roots? Since $f(-2)<0$ and $f(0)>0$, do you agree that $f$ has at least a real root in $(-2,0)$?

Comment: Yes exactly you are right.

Comment: @RobertZ High school contest math.

Comment: @Macavity Thank you.  I wish I could understand this more descriptively in the answer.  I hope I can understand

Comment: @user1094359 Maybe my solution is long (I will be happy to read a better one), but I think it is no so advanced. Take your time to understand it.

Comment: Thanks. Why $\gamma^3=1$ implies $\gamma=1$? Because, we have $3$ complex roots and why you are looking for $-\alpha$, instead of $\alpha$?

Comment: $\gamma$ is real because the given cubic has all real roots. The coefficient $alpha$ is the opposite of the sum of the roots.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4497270/72031